# Image flickering on Listview Search - xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms application, I have a Listview.The Listview contains images which are binded to photoURL.I have implemented a searchbox at the top of listview.Everything worked fine.But the problem now I facing is whenever I search for anything in list,the item appears.But the image will be gets flicker on each character type.I am getting the data from API that binding to the listview.
Please refer the link : https://gfycat.com/WaterloggedBeneficialGlobefish

**My Image binding**

```
 <Grid>
                                         <ci1:CircleImage  
                                             HeightRequest="200"
                                             Source="empavatar.png"
                                             Aspect="AspectFit">
                                         </ci1:CircleImage>
                                         <ci1:CircleImage  
                                             HeightRequest="200"
                                             Source="{Binding PhotoURL}"
                                             Aspect="AspectFit">
                                         </ci1:CircleImage>
                </Grid>
```

Iam using circular imageview and a template image when ImageURL is null.

**My Search**

```
   private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
            {
                EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = resultObjForEmployee;
            }

            else
            {
                EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = resultObjForEmployee.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(e.NewTextValue));
            }
        }
```

*resultObjForEmployee* is the result that I getting from json.

Please help me to recover this problem.

Comment: are you using mvvm or not?

Comment: Yes Iam using MVVM

Comment: the why are you updating your ItemSource like this `EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = resultObjForEmployee;` shouldn't you have a binding ?

Comment: I directly binded the items from json result

Comment: Try setting list view's CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" and then check the impact

Comment: <ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi bro it worked,,,,You are super awesome

Comment: The above could solve the issue `<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">`

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi bro post it as an answer..

Comment: @G.hakim Thanks bro

Comment: Sure no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the **CachingStrategy** of Listview as "**RecycleElement**"

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <ci1:CircleImage  
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        Source="empavatar.png"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"></ci1:CircleImage>
                    <ci1:CircleImage  
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        Source="{Binding PhotoURL}"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"></ci1:CircleImage>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```